# prepared statements on loop and rollback if there are errors

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, prepared-statement

I was hoping someone would guide me in the right direction. What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

user uploads a csv file the data is then stored in a multidimensional array $formatted_payments. Then I check the records on the file against the records on the DB. I need to check if the route from the file matches the route on DB if it does for all records then commit all the updates but if there is one mismatch then i need to rollback all the update. I hope this all makes sense. Here is what I did but I haven't tested yet.

Thank you

```
$conn->autocommit(FALSE);
    $route_errors = [];

    foreach($formatted_payments as $val){

        $sql = "SELECT id, account_no, payment_amount, route_id, payment_date FROM car_payments WHERE payment_date = '".$date."' AND account_no = '".$val['account_no']. "'";
        $res = $conn->query($sql);
        $data = $res->fetch_object();
        if($data){

            if($val['amount'] > 0){

                if($val['route_id'] != $data->route_id){
                    $route_errors[] = $val['account_no'];
                }else{
                    $sql = "UPDATE car_payments SET payment_amount = ? charged = ? WHERE id = ?";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $val['amount'], 'Si', $data->id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                }

            }else{
                $sql = "UPDATE car_payments SET payment_amount = ? charged = ?, pending = ? WHERE id = ?";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $val['amount'], 'No', 1, $data->id);
                $stmt->execute();
            }

        }


    }

    if(!empty($route_errors)){

        $conn->roll_back();

        echo 'The following accounts do not match the route. Records not imported.<br>';
        foreach($route_errors as $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }

    }else{

        $conn->commit();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you asking the question if you haven't tested this code yet? Try it, debug problems, and post a question if you can't figure out a problem.

Comment: because I've never used transactions and I am looking for some guidance before executing it

Comment: Well first I would do prepare outside of the loop.  In other words you can, and should, execute multiple times against the same prepared statement.  Also I hope your tables are innoDB because MyISAM and transactions don't really gel well.  And I don't see `mysqli::begin_transaction` anywhere.